# AUCTeX installation error in Windows

Tags: auctex

I have followed the instructions [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/download-for-windows.html), in a nutshell:

1. download/unpack AUCTeX in a directory for installation
2. download install cygwin
3. download/install Emacs (that was already done)
4. download/install MikTeX (or any other TeX system)

From a cygwin shell I then ran:

```
./configure --prefix="C:\Program Files (x86)\Emacs" --with-texmf-dir="C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin"
```

I am not 100% sure about the location of the TeX installation, however the error I get is the following:

```
checking for make... no
configure: error: make not found, aborting!
```

so i looks like `configure` does not find the `make` program. Indeed, I can't find it on the computer.

Any hints on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Why don't you use ELPA?  It's muuuuuuuuch easier to use and you'll get updates!  You can find installation instructions via ELPA at https://gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html#Installation read the first paragraph

Comment: Well...the _installation_ actually went like a breeze! I do not understand why not put this information in the installation instructions directly, instead of in the bigger manual only.
Thank you for the tip! It actually finds the TeX compiler and everything!