# latex-preview in AUCTeX and org-mode

Tags: auctex, preview-latex

After struggling with `AUCTeX` installation under Windows, I was suggested [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/17084/auctex-installation-error-in-windows) to use `ELPA` and its automatic process to install the package.

Following this, everything went fine and I can now read, process, and export to pdf a `.tex` source within `emacs`.

Also, I have available the `dvipng` program and I can successufully reproduce the steps described [here](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-latex-preview.html) in the section **dvipng setup**.

However, it is the `latex-preview` mechanism which I cannot get to work. Different things happen in `org-mode` and `AUCTeX`:

**AUCTeX** :

After finding a `.tex` file, `Preview`, `LaTeX` and the rest of menus are available, and as said the process of generating a `dvi` and `pdf` flows without issues. However, the `preview on` toggle does not work correctly. I get the following error message:

```
LaTeX: preview-image-type setting 'png unsupported by this Emacs
```

I looked up the specific error string and got [here](http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~s1pan/install_auctex.html), where it is suggested to change the output format from `png` to `pnm` in the `preview-latex.el` file. However, I cannot find this file!!!

**org-mode** :

I insert a `LaTeX` fragment into an `org` file (an equation), then with `C-c C-x C-l` I should have a preview of the output overlayed inline, but I do not see any change in the buffer. Still, I get no error message even if the variable `org-format-latex-signal-error` is set to `non-nil` (which should signal an error in image snippet creation). All I see in the `minibuffer` is the message:

```
Creating image...done. Use `C-c C-c` to remove images.
```

**EDIT**

I made the `AUCTeX` preview work...it involved downloading of dll and correction of launching command for - basically - `ghostview`. There are few steps involved, so I plan to write about them as soon as I have a minute.

`org-mode` preview does not work as of yet, it just shows a white image so I'll have to investigate that.

Comment: Take a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/262959/auctex-preview-image-not-supported  The problem about unsupported png format is addressed also in [AUCTeX manual](https://gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/Installation-under-MS-Windows.html#Installation-under-MS-Windows).  To change a value of a variable, you don't need to edit the original source but you can do it also in your [init file](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html)

Comment: I don't know...I've been adding `.dll`s, installing `ghostview` although this is already available in my `MiKTeX` installation, trying to change to `pnm` instead of `png`...Nothing works.